# What is the group of additive operations on topological K-theory?

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, at.algebraic-topology

Let us view topological K-theory as a functor $K$ from the cateory of compact pairs (that is, a compact Hausdorff spaces with a distinguished closed subset) to the category of $\mathbb Z/2$-graded Abelian groups. We could also restrict to second countable spaces and thus countable groups.

An additive  operation on topological K-theory is just a natural transformation from $K$ to $K$. These natural transformations form an Abelian group under addition.

*Question:* What is the isomorphism class of this group?

Examples of operations are discussed in Efton Park's book and in Max Karoubi's book, but I cannot find discussion of the collection of all (additive) operations.

*Edit:* After looking at Karoubi's book again, I have to state that it actually contains a very satisfactory treatment of operations in K-theory.

Comment: I thought the answer is that this is a ring and that as a ring it is isomorphic to symmetric functions.

Comment: @Bruce Westbury: A ring with respect to composition?

Comment: Aren't symmetric functions related to unstable operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most explicit answers are in work of Sarah Whitehouse and her collaborators.  You could start with this paper and its references:

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2010-138-06/S0002-9939-10-10237-8/home.html

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, the group is uncountable. See

Adams, J. F.; Clarke, F. W.

Stable operations on complex $K$-theory.

Illinois J. Math. 21 (1977), no. 4, 826–829.

Comment: I don't recall, do they cover additive operations explicitly in this paper?

Comment: I have to admit to not having actually read the paper...but doesn't uncountably many degree $0$ stable operations imply uncountably many additive ones (since stable operations are always additive)?

Comment: Mark, yes it does.  I just couldn't remember if that paper had any more detail on the specifics of additive operations.  From what I understand, the request "Please write down a stable operation (other than generated by the two obvious ones)" would still generate a shrug, whereas we know lots about additive operations, so it's worth a paper to say, "There are uncountably many stable operations" but not to say, "There are uncountably many unstable operations".

Comment: (I meant "additive operations" for the last two words)

Comment: Andrew, no I don't think they consider additive operations explicitly.